# How can I deploy only the output in Player Pro

Tags: cdf-format, deployment

I want to know how can I see only the output when I deploy the `Mathematica` notebook in `Player Pro` as in `CDF Player`?

I have gone through this screencast on [How to Encrypt Your Code for Deployment](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/howtoencryptyourcodefordeployment), but I haven't understood it properly.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with CDF player, I can't deploy it

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: For deploying in CDF, you can use `CDF Deploy`. For eg. CDFDeploy[ToFileName["path", "name of cdf"]] path is where you want the cdf to be deployed.  name of cdf is what name do you want to give to cdf which is to be deployed.

Comment: I know, but my code has something that does not let me deploy it, I'm not sure of what it should be.

Comment: As far as I know, cdf cannot have dynamic import. May be your code has dynamic importing.

Comment: If it can't have dynamic, what should I use to make dynamic content? - Imagine I want to have an InputField and a Button, I input a value in the InputField and then pressing the button will append this value to a list, and this list is gonna be printed in some plot - Everytime I press the Button, the listplot must be refreshed. - How can it be done?

Comment: I shouldn't be bothering you with such a thing, But I just remembered of the problem I'm having.

Comment: Ok, i've watched the video you suggested. In what part are you stuck?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4060/discussion-between-gustavo-bandeira-and-jennifer)

Comment: @GustavoBandeira -- See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

If your question is really *"How do I remove the input?"*, then you can evaluate

```
NotebookPut[DeleteCases[NotebookGet[], Cell[_, "Input", ___], Infinity]]
```

to create a fresh copy of a notebook with no `Input` cells in it. Then save as CDF.

Comment: Its working fine when I execute the code for  once. But when I  I am closing Mathematica, cdf is not working. Why? How can I rectify this

Answer (score 4):

Consider two versions of CDF:

Deployed

- Save as -> cdf (not deployed): you can see literally the source code via
  hitting shift+ctrl+E (hard to comprehend though ).

Deploy a cdf without showing source code:

- click the output in your notebook.
- choose File -> Deploy -> Standalone -> current selection
- export this cdf to the selected location

You can also, copy the out put and simply paste it into a new CDF document.

---

You can typically make what you want to do with input work by hardcoding possible selections rather than free input.  Make a `List[]` of options that some selection mechanism will access.  Your selection of input just becomes another dynamic element. This should achieve what you want.

Note: you can also access any of Wolfram's computable data within a CDF.

Best if you can post an example of what you have tried.  Then responders can give you more specific solutions.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent your code from appearing in the CDF file, simply double-click on the innermost cell bracket of your output cell. This collapses the input cell. Then select File...Deploy...Standalone...[save entire file)].  The resultant CDF file will neither show the input code nor allow it to be seen at all (since the cell bracket will not be available).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the methods already suggested by others:

If you would like to have a CDF that consists of a single `Manipulate` you can simply copy the Manipulate box itself (i.e., the output of the `Manipulate`) to an empty notebook and save that as a CDF. If initialization with external variables is required use the `Manipulate` option `SaveDefinitions->True` and/or wrap your `Manipulate` in a `DynamicModule`.